# Hangman Game: One word is given, how can I give it a list

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a Hangman game in Python. In the code, the word to be guessed is written. How can I change that to a list, and have a random word be chosen?

Here is my code:

```
print("What's your guess?")

word = "word"
guesses = ''

turns = 10

while turns > 0:
    failed = 0
    for char in word:
        if char in guesses:
            print(char)
        else:
            print("_")
            failed = failed + 1
    if failed == 0:
        print("You won")

        break

    guess = input("guess a character:")
    guesses = guess + guesses

    if guess not in word:

        turns = turns - 1

        print("Wrong")

        print("You have", + turns, "more guesses")

        if turns == 0:
            print("You lost, sorry")
```

Comment: Use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). With that you can do: `word = random.choice(['word','otherword','thirdword'])`

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
wordlist = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
i = random.randint(0, len(wordlist)-1)
word = wordlist[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). Just replace `word = "word"` with the following:

```
words_to_guess = ["queueing", "strength", "sesquipedalianism"]
word = random.choice(words_to_guess)
```

It will pick a random word from the provided list.

As a side note, you can also improve your prints setting the `end` parameter of the `print` function to an empty string. Then your entire word will be printed in one line:

```
        if char in guesses:
            print(char, end="")
        else:
            print("_", end="")
```

You may want to add an empty line `\n` before the "guess your character:" line then:

```
    guess = input("\nguess a character:")
```